# Stock email client doesn't load email + images (screens provided)

Tags: email

I am trying the stock email client and I have used my live email account to check it out. Unfortunately, when I open a message I don't get the full email with the pictures like on the computer. For this to happen, I have to press at "load more details" on the end of the message. Also, I can't get the new emails without refreshing the account through the app.

How can I "fix this?"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the images, you should ramp up the "Size to Retrieve" value. 
Most images are in the ten or hundreds of kilobytes.

For the sync-

The first thing you should try is -- from the homescreen, 
Menu>Settings>Accounts&Sync> and ensure that sync is enabled for the email client.

-However-
You may not have a version of the stock email client that supports the exchange push protocol. (Such a thing used to exist, although I'm fairly sure *all* stock mail clients support exchange, nowadays) 
Or else, you may need to remove the account and manually re-add it as an account that uses "Exchange" -

HTH!